# Error on raising ValidationError as dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

Django newbie here. I am trying to raise an error for email field in my custom form. My forms.py has following code to validate email:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(email=email)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                return email
        raise ValueError({'email':'Email already registered. 
                     Login to continue or use another email.'})
```

On entering existing email again, I get following error on my debug screen of app:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I am following this [LINK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

**EDIT**
Getting this error on changing ValueError to ValidationError The argument `field` must be `None` when the `error` argument contains errors for multiple fields.

Comment: why are you passing a dict?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am passing a dict to raise error for Email.

Comment: Couldn't you use a string and pass the email using str.format if you want to show the email? `"Email: {} already registered. Login to continue or use another email".format(email)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not sure what to change. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Use `ValidationError("Email: {} already registered. Login to continue or use another email".format(email))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Using just clean(self) throws no error now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `raise ValidationError` instead of `raise ValueError`:

```
def clean(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        User._default_manager.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return self.cleaned_data
    raise ValidationError({'email':'Email already registered. Login to continue or use another email.'})
```

Comment: Getting this error now: `The argument field must be None when the `error` argument contains errors for multiple fields.`

Comment: You should pass string instead of dictionary to exception. I've provided example.

Comment: That's the issue. I want to raise error for Email (field_error)specifically and not general error(non_field_error)

Comment: In that case I think you should rename clean_email to clean.

Comment: If you use clean_<fieldname>, don't specify a dictionary.  Any ValidationError that is raised is automatically associated with that field.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be raising ValueError, you should be raising `forms.ValidationError`.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Its ValidationError. See the error now.

Answer (score 3):

When using `clean_<fieldname>`, don't specify a dictionary.  Any `ValidationError` that is raised in that method is automatically associated with that field.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        User._default_manager.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email
    raise ValidationError('Email already registered. 
                 Login to continue or use another email.')
```